# How can I print in black and white in Evince?

Tags: printing, colors, evince

What option should I select in the (Evince) print dialog to print in black and white using only the (cheaper) black ink cartridge - not black as a composite of other colours?

The options I see in the 'Colour' tab are:

- 'Grayscale'
- 'Inverted Grayscale'
- 'RGB Color'
- 'CMY Color'
- 'CMYK'
- 'KCMY'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You usually want Grayscale. At least it works like that on all the printers that I know. Of course it could be driver-dependent, so more data about the printer model could yield you a better answer.